# In my table number is going out side the cell

Tags: tables

Question: In my table last columns text is going out side of the cell.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{makecell, multirow}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newrobustcmd\B{\DeclareFontSeriesDefault[rm]{bf}{b}\bfseries}                          
\usepackage[skip=1ex, font=small, labelfont=bf]{caption}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht]
    \centering
\sisetup{detect-weight,
         mode=text}
    \setcellgapes{5pt}
    \makegapedcells
\caption{My Table}
%\label{tab:...}
 %   \label{tab:my-table}
\begin{tabular}{|*{7}{S[table-format=1.1]|}
                                  }
\hline
{\multirow{2.4}{*}{$P_{r}$}} & {\multirow{2.4}{*}{$N_{r}$}} & {\multirow{2.4}{*}{$A^{*}$}} & {\multirow{2.4}{*}{$B^{*}$}} & {\multirow{2.4}{*}{$E_{C}$}} & {\multirow{2.4}{*}{$\gamma$}} & {\multirow{2.4}{*}{$Re_{x^{-1/2}} N u_{x}$}}        \\ 
         &         &           &        &          &            &                    \\  \hline
\B  3    &\B 5    &\B 1.2      &\B 1    &\B 0.5    & 1          & 0.0096352877        \\ \hline
\B  3.1  & 5      & 1.2        & 1      & 0.5      & 1          &         \\ \hline
\B  3.2  & 5      & 1.2        & 1      & 0.5      & 1          &           \\ \hline
3        &\B 5.1  & 1.2        & 1      & 0.5      & 1          &         \\ \hline
3        &\B 5.2  & 1.2        & 1      & 0.5      & 1          &         \\ \hline
3        &\B 5.3  & 1.2        & 1      & 0.5      & 1          &            \\ \hline
3        & 5      &\B 1.3      & 1      & 0.5      & 1          &           \\ \hline
3        & 5      &\B 1.4      & 1      & 0.5      & 1          &            \\ \hline
3        & 5      &\B 1.5      & 1      & 0.5      & 1          &             \\ \hline
3        & 5      & 1.2        &\B 1.1  & 0.5      & 1          &           \\ \hline
3        & 5      & 1.2        &\B 1.2  & 0.5      & 1          &          \\ \hline
3        & 5      & 1.2        &\B 1.3  & 0.5      & 1          &          \\ \hline
3        & 5      & 1.2        & 1      &\B 0.2    & 1          &          \\ \hline
3        & 5      & 1.2        & 1      &\B 0.3    & 1          &       \\ \hline
3        & 5      & 1.2        & 1      &\B 0.4    & 1          &         \\ \hline
3        & 5      & 1.2        & 1      & 0.5      & \B 1.1     &          \\ \hline
3        & 5      & 1.2        & 1      & 0.5      & \B 1.2     &       \\ \hline
3        & 5      & 1.2        & 1      & 0.5      & \B 1.3     &         \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: {|*{6}{S[table-format=1.1]|}S[table-format=1.10]|} instead of you original cumn specifiers should fix that.

Comment: @ leandriis Would you please paste revised code.

Comment: @leandriis Your tricks isn't working

Comment: unrelated but why are you using multrow here? for the actual question you have told the table to allocate enough room for format 1.1 so 1 decimal place and you have used many decimal places in the data, so it doesn't fit, but you haven't said what you want to happen, do you want a column to fit the data as shown or do you want to round the value to fit the specified column?

Comment: also `\DeclareFontSeriesDefault` would normally be used at most once per document, to set up bold font choices, but you are using it every time you switch to bold

Comment: @David Carlisle Sir Actually here I am looking for nice table in which my all text fix nicely.  Please sir guide me I know that I don't have enough knowledge for tabular environment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just as @leandriis said, you only have to change your column definitions. Right now, using `|*{7}{S[table-format=1.1]|}`, you tell latex you want 7 columns in which you have numbers with one digit before and one digit after the decimal point, and that's how they will be aligned. As you have 10 digits behind the decimal point in your last column, latex simply does the spacing wrong because you provided incorrect information. What you want is 6 columns with format '1.1' (one digit before and one after the decimal point) and after that another column with format '1.10'. You can achieve this writig `|*{6}{S[table-format=1.1]|} S[table-format=1.10]|`.

As you do not seem to be interested in optimizing your tabular further, I didn't change anything else in your code.

```
\begin{tabular}{|*{6}{S[table-format=1.1]|} S[table-format=1.10]|}
   \hline
   {\multirow{2.4}{*}{$P_{r}$}} & {\multirow{2.4}{*}{$N_{r}$}} & {\multirow{2.4}{*}{$A^{*}$}} & {\multirow{2.4}{*}{$B^{*}$}} & {\multirow{2.4}{*}{$E_{C}$}} & {\multirow{2.4}{*}{$\gamma$}} & {\multirow{2.4}{*}{$Re_{x^{-1/2}} N u_{x}$}} \\
           &        &        &        &        &        &              \\ \hline
   \B  3   & \B 5   & \B 1.2 & \B 1   & \B 0.5 & 1      & 0.0096352877 \\ \hline
   \B  3.1 & 5      & 1.2    & 1      & 0.5    & 1      &              \\ \hline
   \B  3.2 & 5      & 1.2    & 1      & 0.5    & 1      &              \\ \hline
   % Put rest of your rows here.
\end{tabular}
```

(Note: As I don't have `makecell` installed, I commented it out, so maybe the result will look a bit different from yours. Furthermore this code is *not* compilable because I didn't want to copy&paste everything, but only the part you have to adapt.)
[image]

Comment: Now it working. I am Very Surprise. Thanks to all